Issues Signing XML with RSASSA-PSS (SHA256-RSA-MGF1) Using PHP
I'm trying to sign an XML document using the RSASSA-PSS (SHA256-RSA-MGF1) algorithm in PHP. I created a certificate with the following OpenSSL command:
openssl req -newkey rsa-pss -new -nodes -x509 -days 3650 -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:4096 -sigopt rsa_pss_saltlen:32 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem

After generating the certificate and private key, I attempted to sign the XML document using the robrichards/xmlseclibs library. However, when I link the <Reference> to the <Object>, I encounter a Digest error, and the signature verification fails. And it turns out that the library does not support this algorithm.
Here's the relevant PHP code:
$objDSig = new XMLSecurityDSig();

$objDSig->setCanonicalMethod(XMLSecurityDSig::C14N);
$objDSig->addObject($dip,null,null);
$objDSig->addReference(
    $xmlDoc,
    XMLSecurityDSig::SHA256,
    array('http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature')
);

//XMLSecurityKey::RSASSA_PSS custom code jochen-jung using phpseclib/phpseclib
$objKey = new XMLSecurityKey(XMLSecurityKey::RSASSA_PSS, array('type'=>'private'));
$objKey->loadKey($this->primary_key, TRUE);
$objDSig->sign($objKey);
$objDSig->add509Cert(file_get_contents($this->certificate), true, false, ['subjectName'=>true]);
$objDSig->appendSignature($xmlDoc->documentElement);

I've already realized that the ext-openssl extension in PHP doesn't fully support this algorithm, which is why I switched to phpseclib. I came across Jochen Jung's code https://github.com/robrichards/xmlseclibs/pull/262, which seemed to work, but I can't replicate the success.
Questions:

Has anyone successfully signed an XML document using RSASSA-PSS (SHA256-RSA-MGF1) in PHP?
Are there any known issues with phpseclib for this specific use case?
Is there a specific approach or library I should be using to ensure the signature passes verification?

I found that the Digest verification passes successfully when the URI in the <ds:Reference> element is an empty string, like URI="". However, when I use something like URI="#pfx784add6d-1227-7ac4-10a0-ce5532815998", I encounter issues.
Despite this, the <Signature> has never passed verification using the Chilkat XML Digital Signature Validator . I expected that if the Digest verification passes, the signature should also pass, but this hasn't been the case.
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:dpi="urn:oecd:ties:dpi:v1">
<ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/xmldsig-more#sha256-rsa-MGF1"/>
<ds:Reference URI="#pfx784add6d-1227-7ac4-10a0-ce5532815998">
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
<ds:DigestValue>47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue>OrCZl+uY69KxnSQnoXw3...</ds:SignatureValue>
<ds:KeyInfo>
<ds:X509Data>
<ds:X509SubjectName>TEST</ds:X509SubjectName>
<ds:X509Certificate>MIIGWTCCBBGgAwIBAgIUPqVSOTIBUtd6BkNxaEsusYuKEZAwPQYJKo...</ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
<ds:Object Id="pfx784add6d-1227-7ac4-10a0-ce5532815998">
...
</ds:Object>
</ds:Signature>

Has anyone been able to sign XML documents using this algorithm?
